# Is it possible to run HAProxy load balancer on Windows Server 2012 R2 Base for production?

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2012-r2, load-balancing, haproxy, nlb

I want to run HAProxy on Windows Server 2012 R2 Base for production. I read this blog: http://zcourts.com/2012/09/29/install-haproxy-on-windows-cygwin-good-for-testing and it conveys that HAProxy on Windows is good for testing.

If not HAProxy, what other load balancing solution is good for Windows Server 2012 R2 Base?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely avoid ported applications, when you can use native ones fee-free, especially when it's opensource. For example you can run haproxy on a VM inside a Windows host under Hyper-V, if you're that much into Windows. But in reality I would not either, because this makes you dependant on the Windows IP stack, and I doubt anyone would want this in a production when he has other choices, especially when said stack has bugs like [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms11-083.aspx).

And I strongly advise not to use cygwin-compiled ones. For at least the same reasons, plus nobody, and I mean it, *nobody* will be interested in a bug if you'll find one in a cygwin-compiled application. It's hard to make a bug-report developer-friendly, and this task gets -9000 karma when you are reporting a bug found in a cygwin-compiled software.